# Unable to setup and run LeanFT Runtime Engine on Build machine VM

Tags: leanft

I have LeanFT SDK and Runtime engine installed on my local machine for automation testing using Visual Studio and Selenium.  I use LeanFT and Selenium for automation testing.  We connect to LeanFT runtime engine through the use of a license server, which is dependent upon us having access to VPN.  My team would like to run these tests for every CI/CD build/release using VSTS.  We have a pool of VMs dedicated for automation tests runs, which is already on VPN.

From the link below, it seems all that I need to do get tests run remotely on a VM is to install and have the LeanFT runtime engine installed.

[Additional Information on running LeanFT runtime engine on CI/CD system](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.03/HelpCenter/Content/HowTo/CI_Tools.htm)

In my effort to do that I get the following issue where I cannot access the License server on the build machine which has a connection to the client internal VPN.  The weird thing is authenticating to the license server on my local works fine.  However on the VPN we get the error you see below.  Please help me resolve this. What could be wrong?  We just want the LeanFT runtime engine running on this remote machine.

[image: Unable to Authenticate to License Server on Remote Machine VM]

Comment: From the VPN can you ping the license server machine?

Comment: You should also check this official documentation resource on how to [Run tests remotely](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.03/HelpCenter/Content/HowTo/RunRemotely.htm)